# How high of a priority should one place on making kiddish before chatzot on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, kiddush, tefillah-betzibbur

For example, if the minyan finishes after chatzot yom, is it permitted or proper do daven b'yachidus in order to make kiddush before chatzot, or is it better to daven with the minyan, and hear/make kiddush after chatzot?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are focused on making Kiddush before Chatzot: if it's to avoid fasting, then just drink water before prayers; it it's so you have your first meal before Chatzot, then just say that.

Comment: In any ordinary situation, there should be no need to decide between Amida with a Minyan and eating before Chatzot. In the worst case where Musaf drags on, you can go out and eat at any point that isn't the silent Amida (eg. after Haftarah)

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked your question on [dinonline.com](http://dinonline.org/2016/11/17/fasting-on-shabbos/). Their answer is:

> One should try lechatchilah to daven in a minyan that finishes before
>   chatzos, but bedieved it is better to stay at Shul and pray with a
>   minyan. (Some say the 6 hours from when you got up not chatzos, some
>   say a drink is enough and most people drink before davening).

Their Sources:

> O:CH 288:1 MIshnah Berurah 1,  Magen Avrohom O:CH 157:1 ibid Pri
>   Megodim Eshel Avrohom 3, Mateh Efrayim 597 Elef Hamogen 2

Indeed, you should also view O:CH 288:1 MIshnah Berurah 2 that cites sources that are lenient regarding the rule against fasting on Shabbat that it doesn't apply to someone who is davening. The key, though, is to keep in mind that *chatzot* is based on *sha'ot zemaniyot*. So, this is a concern moreso during the winter, as the Mishnah Berurah states. During the summer, it seems that there would be no priority at all, as the fasting concern isn't even there.

Comment: "most people drink before davening" I'm not sure that's really accurate